# How to access only one cell from a list inside a list

Tags: python, sudoku

I'm making code to initialize a sudoku grid where n^2 is the board size and alpha the percentage of cells that will be filled. But when I try to change only one cell in question, a whole column changed and I don't know how to solve

```
enter code here
import random
def inicializagrelha(n,alpha): 
#A grelha vai ser uma lista com listas... O numero de listas vai ser n^2 e o tamanho de 
cada lista é n^2
if alpha <= 0 or alpha > 1: 
    return "Error"  #O alpha tem de estar sempre entre 0 e 1
numeropreencher = 0
numeropreencher = round((n**4) * alpha) #numero de casas que tem de preencher
grelha = []
listaux = []
for k in range(n * n):
    listaux.append(0)
    grelha.append(listaux)

count = 0
celulaspreenchidas = []

while(count < numeropreencher):
    aux = random.randint(1,n**4)
    if aux not in celulaspreenchidas: 
        celulaspreenchidas.append(aux)
        linha = 0
        coluna = 0 
        
        for j in range(0,n**2): 
            if (j+1)*(n**2)-aux<n**2: 
                linha = j
                if (j+1)*n**2-aux == 0: 
                    coluna = 0
                coluna = (n**2)-((j+1)*n**2-aux)-1
                
        print(linha,coluna,aux)
        grelha[linha][coluna] = aux
        count += 1

    else: 
        aux = random.randint(1,n**4)


return grelha
inicializagrelha(3,0.2)
```

Comment: in your code i didn't see any code for updating single column?

Comment: The problem is the line grelha.append(listaux)

Comment: `grelha.append(listaux)` does NOT create new lists; each thing you append is a reference to the same list, so its changes will be reflected in all the places it's used.

Comment: It is supposed to update the line and column on the same time

Comment: @RandomDavis thanks a lot, how should i change it?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
grelha = []
listaux = []
for k in range(n * n):
    listaux.append(0)
    grelha.append(listaux)
```

to

```
grelha = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

"**But why?**" *you ask.*

In the first, let's step through what's going on. In iterating through the loop from `k=0` to `k=n-1` (let's assume for now that `n=3` to keep things simple), the below happens:

```
grelha = []
listaux = []

k = 0
listaux.append(0)      -> now listaux = [0]
grelha.append(listaux) -> now grelha  = [[0]]

k = 1
listaux.append(0)      -> now listaux = [0, 0]
grelha.append(listaux) -> now grelha  = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

But wait! Why did the **first** element in `grelha` change? Because when you append `listaux` to `grelha` you're really just putting a reference to `listaux` there. So in the 2nd iteration, when you *change* `listaux`, it changes the **first** element in `grelha`.  Continuing, we'd see that

```
k = 2
listaux.append(0)      -> now listaux = [0, 0, 0]
grelha.append(listaux) -> now grelha  = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

and it keeps going! Now if we change, for example, `grelha[1][1] = 5` we see

```
>>> grelha
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0]]
```

because each sub-list of `grelha` refers to the *same* list.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked <3